# One user - 2 reports - 2 behaviours

Tags: reporting, customization

I have a user, whom is trying to edit reports.

The settings for the user profile is ok

[image]

1. When looking at the 2 reports in issue, both reports were created by the user.
2. Both reports show different buttons when looking at them

**report 1:**

[image: No Save button - but with Customize button]

**report 2:**

[image: No customize - but with Save button]

The only difference I see is that the report without the `Save` button, is in a public dashboard folder.
[image]

However, this folder is read/write enabled to all internal users
[image]

[image]

The main problem is that when the user created a report, he can't customize it. Weird

Answer (score 2):

The user's profile must also have the Manage Public Reports permission checked.

Also, you should take a look at the new report and dashboard folder permissions available in Summer '13. It gives you much granular control over who can work with reports per folder.

Comment: It does not explain the missing of the customize button on the users own report.

Comment: I'm pretty sure once a report gets created in a folder, the permissions for that folder are used. Report ownership doesn't count for much.